# Fine Uploader: Change the file's name

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm trying to save files with some directory structure into my S3 bucket, but getName method only returns the reference not the value of the getName method.

getName ---> [object Object].
https://mybucket/2016/04/13/%5Bobject+Object%5D

```
<script>
        $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
           debug: true,
            template: 'qq-template-s3',
            request: {
                endpoint: "myendpoint.s3.amazonaws.com", 
                accessKey: "my_key"
            },
            objectProperties: {
                key: function (fileId) { 
                return '2016/04/13/' + $("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3("getName",fileId); 
                }
           }
...
```

How can I edit the name of the file to file's UID or file's name using the jQuery API? Tks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your code:

```
return '2016/04/13/' + $("#fineuploader-s3").fineUploaderS3("getName",fileId);
```

...should be:

```
return '2016/04/13/' + $("#fine-uploader-s3").fineUploaderS3("getName",fileId);
```

But this could have been avoided simply by *not* using jQuery to wrap Fine Uploader. There's really [no reason to use jQuery in this context](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310). Here's what your code looks like without the jQuery wrapper:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
   element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-s3"), 
   template: "qq-template-s3",
   request: {
       endpoint: "myendpoint.s3.amazonaws.com",
       accessKey: "my_key"
   },
   objectProperties: {
       key: function (fileId) {
           return '2016/04/13/' + this.getName(fileId);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tks Ray. I agree with you, works fine without jQuery.